# How does Python adds a scalar in a matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a **3x3** zero matrix

```
a = [
[0,0,0],
[0,0,0],
[0,0,0]
]
```

Suppose I want to add `1` to the first element of the matrix. I use :

```
a[0][0] += 1
```

I thought it would add 1 to the `a[0][0]`th element and the matrix `a` would be :

```
a = [
[1,0,0],
[0,0,0],
[0,0,0]
]
```

But , in reality the matrix is now :

```
a = [
[1,0,0],
[1,0,0],
[1,0,0]
]
```

Why is `1` added to `a[0][1]` and `a[0][2]`
also ?

Full snippet :

```
a = [[0] * 3] * 3 
a[0][0] += 1
print(a)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly). By doing `[...] * x` you create references to the same list object. You need to create independent lists for each row. Also, if you're going to work with multi-dimensional arrays, you might prefer using [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```py
>>> a = [[0]*3]*3 
>>> a[0][0] = 1
>>> a
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
>>>
>>> b=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
>>> b[0][0] = 1
>>> b
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

So what happened here? Perhaps you misunderstand what multiplication `[X]*3` does. The result is `[X, X, X]` where `X` is **reference** to the underlying object, not a (deep) copy. Which is what you want.

Your `a` list is a list with 3 elements, each one being literally the same list. While my `b` list is a list with 3 **different** lists, which happen to have the same values inside.

---

If you want to create such matrix with pure Python, then you can utilize this code:

```py
def create_matrix(rows, columns, default_value=0):
    result = []
    for _ in range(rows):
        row = []
        for __ in range(columns):
            row.append(default_value)
        result.append(row)
    return result

a = create_matrix(3, 3)
```

I suggest looking at numpy (or similar) as well.

Comment: So , is there any way around this or I have to manually write `a=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]` every time?

Comment: @NeoNØVÅ7 I've updated the answer.

Comment: Just now I tried this code `a = [ [0 for _ in range(3)] for p in range(3) ]` . This gives me my expected answer , but will it also be a "pure" matrix of unique element ids ?

Comment: @NeoNØVÅ7 that's fine as well.

Comment: That is a nice answer, but why answer an obvious duplicate?